# Using charts in HTML wil chart.js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn how to create graphs using chart.js, but for some reason my chart isn't showing up on my webpage

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="width: 900px; height: 400px;">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-v3ygConQmvH0QehvQa6gSvTE2VdBZ6wkLOlmK7Mcy2mZ0ZF9saNbbk19QeaoTHdWIEiTlWmrwAL4hS8ElnGFbA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script>

        let labels = ['Big Mac', 'QuarterPounder', 'Mcdouble', 'Doubler Cheeseburger', 'Hamburger'];
        let itemData = [550, 520, 400, 450, 250];

        const data = {
            labels: labels,
            dataset: [{
                data: itemData,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(66,221, 245)'
            }]
        };

        const config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data
        };

        const chart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart'),
            config
        );
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: There are two issues: A) a typo: it's `datasets: [{...` (not `dataset`) and B) to use charts.js with standard scripts you need to link to `charts.umd.js`, the version you linked to works with module scripts. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lreqjs2/)